# Mercurial and nginx. Error 10054

Tags: mercurial, timeout, nginx, urlopen

When I push files to the server, then after 60 seconds i get "urlopen error [Errno 10054]". I think it's because i push large files.
I use nginx web-server with fast-cgi process. What nginx parametr responsible to that 60sec timeout? Or maybe i should see to another way?

Comment: How are you pushing?  http?  ssh?

Answer (score 8):

Please refer to: http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=2716.

If you are using latest TortoiseHg client, just put below config to your mercurial.ini:

```
[ui]
usehttp2=true
```

Comment: +1 Thx, worked for me. *Note for others:* I've tried to put the config directly to repo's .hgrc, but that did not helped. Putting to `mercurial.ini` is needed!

Comment: Works for me too. Thank you very much. Since I started using Mercurial I've always had this problem and now thanks to you it is solved.